# Vapourise Predef.any2stringadd in interpreter

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I am having problem with `Predef.any2stringadd` that unfortunately is [officially considered not a PITA](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-194). I changed my API from

```
trait Foo {
   def +(that: Foo): Foo
}
```

to a type class approach

```
object Foo {
   implicit def fooOps(f: Foo): Ops = new Ops(f)
   final class Ops(f: Foo) {
      def +(that: Foo): Foo = ???
   }
}
trait Foo
```

Now I can hide that horrible method in *compiled code* like this:

```
import Predef.{any2stringadd => _}
```

However, this fails in my REPL/interpreter environment.

```
val in = new IMain(settings, out)
in.addImports("Predef.{any2stringadd => _}") // has no effect?
```

How can I tell the interpreter to vapourise this annoying method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround seems to be to take the implicit conversion out of `Foo`'s companion object, and place it in the top hierarchy (package object in my real case):

```
object Foo {
//   implicit def fooOps(f: Foo): Ops = new Ops(f)
   final class Ops(f: Foo) {
      def +(that: Foo): Foo = ???
   }
}
trait Foo
implicit def fooOps(f: Foo): Foo.Ops = new Foo.Ops(f)
```

While I don't know why that should make any difference, it appears it does enough to make the interpreter forget about `any2stringadd`.

(Still, I think a new ticket should be opened in an attempt to remove that method, also given that string interpolation in Scala 2.10 will make it more superfluous.)